# SSIS MySQL ADO.net SQL Task Input & Output

Tags: mysql, input, ssis, ado.net, output

I am trying to use a SQL Task in Visual Studio SSIS to get two output values stored to variables.

I have done a range of Googling on the issue and have been able to get inserts working but I can't seem to see the output values to come out.

I am have tried using both '?' and @NameVariables but I am not having much luck.

```
SELECT `LocalUnitCode`,`IBDAuditCode` 
FROM `tablename`.`provenance`
WHERE `DataCaptureTool` <> 'DataCaptureTool'
AND RIGHT(REVERSE(`IBDR_Source`),LENGTH(`IBDR_Source`)-LOCATE('_',REVERSE(`IBDR_Source`))) = ?;
```

OR

```
SELECT `LocalUnitCode`,`IBDAuditCode` 
FROM `tablename`.`provenance`
WHERE `DataCaptureTool` <> 'DataCaptureTool'
AND RIGHT(REVERSE(`IBDR_Source`),LENGTH(`IBDR_Source`)-LOCATE('_',REVERSE(`IBDR_Source`))) = @Source;
```

OR

```
SET @LocalUnitCode = 
(SELECT `LocalUnitCode` 
FROM `tablename`.`provenance`
WHERE `DataCaptureTool` <> 'DataCaptureTool'
AND RIGHT(REVERSE(`IBDR_Source`),LENGTH(`IBDR_Source`)-LOCATE('_',REVERSE(`IBDR_Source`))) = @Source);
```

Not quite sure if the syntax is a problem or the parameter mapping or the result set needs changing. If I try and follow the guide that are using for SQL Server it does not appear to function correctly.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks,

David

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is the code I am using in the SQL Statement:

```
SELECT ? = `LocalUnitCode`, ? = `IBDAuditCode` 
FROM `ibdr_staging_K`.`provenance`
WHERE `DataCaptureTool` <> 'DataCaptureTool'
AND RIGHT(REVERSE(`IBDR_Source`),LENGTH(`IBDR_Source`)-LOCATE('_',REVERSE(`IBDR_Source`))) = ?;
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Post some screenshots of your Execute SQL Task. Main tab, the Parameters and Result Sets, if you would

Comment: Here is the error message I currently am getting: [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "SELECT ? = `LocalUnitCode`, ? = `IBDAuditCode` 
FR..." failed with the following error: "String[1]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: For a  connection type ADO.NET you should use @parametername to map to the variables, which you may define in the Parameter Mapping tab

Answer (score 1):

Example of mapping variables to parameters in ADO.NET:

[image]

SQL:

```sql
SELECT @LocalUnitCode = `LocalUnitCode`, @AuditCode = `IBDAuditCode` 
FROM `ibdr_staging_K`.`provenance`
WHERE `DataCaptureTool` <> 'DataCaptureTool'
AND RIGHT(REVERSE(`IBDR_Source`),LENGTH(`IBDR_Source`)-LOCATE('_',REVERSE(`IBDR_Source`))) = @Source;
```

Comment: Tried this option and I get the following error message. [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "SELECT LocalUnitCode = LocalUnitCode, AuditCode ..." failed with the following error: "String[1]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: Removed @ symbol from the error fyi. I had assume there would be no result set as the values are passing into a variable.

Comment: Result set none is correct because it will output to variables. Have you defined the variables ETL_ .. in SSIS variables? Also they should match the data type of the columns they are paired with.

Comment: Yes I have two variable defined in SSIS 1) ETL_ID_Provenance_AuditCode 2) ETL_ID_Provenance_LocalUnitCode and both are set to String

Comment: I have updated the parameter definition picture including the size of the output parameters, I put 30 but you can set it to match the length of the columns.

Comment: That all works and goes through on SSIS but the variables are not updating with the values so the SSIS variables are not storing the details which seems odd. I have checked the query by replacing the values and I do get results out. Seems odd that the values are not changing.

Comment: Maybe the input variable @source is not populated when the query runs. You can test it by hardcoding the value in the query,  to narrow down the issue to the output.

Comment: I have tried running the code with it hard coded like so: `SELECT @LocalUnitCode = LocalUnitCode, @AuditCode = IBDAuditCode FROM ibdr_staging_K.provenance WHERE DataCaptureTool <> 'DataCaptureTool' AND RIGHT(REVERSE(IBDR_Source),LENGTH(IBDR_Source)-LOCATE('_',REVERSE(IBDR_Source))) = '1_1';` But sadly this is still not populating the two variables. The task goes through on SSIS without failure but the values are not populated and I have tried putting a watch on the key fields. Not sure what else to try on this all seems like it should work.